# A-frame inspector disappears

Tags: aframe, inspector

When using the A-frame inspector, it will appear when use CTL+ALT+I - however the side panel on the right has disappeared. When I select the a-scene that appears. However when I select an object to move around the scene the whole inspector disappears and it will not come back unless I refresh the page.

I opened the a-frame inspector and selected an object to move. I expected the inspector panels (left and right) to appear and show me the scale, position etc

Comment: I know it’s been a month since this was raised, but for anyone still curious about this, see this git issue: https://github.com/c-frame/aframe-physics-system/issues/32

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to be clicking on an object with aframe-physics-system component? Not sure if you're getting the same error, but it's likely that the Aframe inspector crashed. This has happened to me when I was trying to select a physics object in the scene. When I open the browser console logs, it says something about a React error

```
index.js:303 Error: Minified React error #185; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=185 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

that links to:

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

[Screenshot of the Aframe inspector error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuSNs.jpg)

Example physics example that breaks inspector: https://c-frame.github.io/aframe-physics-system/examples/ammo/sandbox.html